# Preloading images without triggering the "loading" icon on the browser

Tags: javascript, css, preload

I'm aware I can pre-load an image like such:

CSS:

```
#preload {
  background-image: url('image-to-be-preloaded.png');
}
```

JS:

```
(new Image()).src = 'image-to-be-preloaded.png';
```

When the aforementioned image is being loaded, however, the browser displays the "loading icon" (on Firefox and Chrome, this is in the icon on the tab). Can I preload images without the user feeling like the page is still loading?

Comment: The css isnt really pre-loading its just loading.  In the old days you just used to add a display:none to a class and then add the class to an image.  This would preload the image before it was actually required in the page... for rollovers for example

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by ajax:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",'image-to-be-preloaded.png',true);
xhr.send(null);
```

But **#preload** must be invisible element. If **#preload** is visible, than css engine auto start load background-image.

P.S. This code not working in IE8. For old browers you need use other ajax function.